# jQuery Tooltip on Selectize

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip, selectize.js

I am trying to add a jQuery tooltip on a Selectize (http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/) select box, however for some reason I'm having some problems.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#myDropdown").selectize({
    onChange: function(value) {
      var ddOptions = {
        1: triggerOpt1,
        2: triggerOpt2,
        3: triggerOpt3,
        4: triggerOpt4
      };

      ddOptions[value]();
    },
    render: {
      option: showItem,
      item: showItem
    }
  });

  $("#myDropdown .ddOption").tooltip({
    position: "bottom left",
    offset: [-2, 10],
    opacity: 0.9
  });

});

function showItem(data) {
  return Handlebars.templates["dropdown"]({
    itemClass: data.value,
    label: data.text,
    title: I18n["ddOption_" + data.value]
  });
}
```

```html
<select id="myDropdown">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

For some reason, I am not getting the jQuery tooltip but the native browser tooltip.  When I try to attach the tooltip in the console it works fine..

Has anyone ever encountered this issue?

**EDIT**:  the class ddOption is being added to the selectize items in the handlebars template.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Selectize but I can figure out it is based on jQuery-ui's selectmenu with which I experienced same problem.

The underlying cause is that jquery-UI hides actual select element and build an entirely new one with other html which simulates it and synchronize its value to original select tag.

So, if you capture it, for example, by it's id or class to do anything, you end up modifying a hidden element.

You should search for a sibling span with the ui-selectmenu-button class instead. But better use your preferred browser inspector to see it's actual attributes uses selectize plugin.

Comment: Yes, but I think with cunning css it's possible to select the sibling element

Answer (score 0):

ddOptions is JS array type.. you need html element to get hover intent..
so try below code .. it might help you out...

```
$("#myDropdown option").tooltip({
    position: "bottom left",
    offset: [-2, 10],
    opacity: 0.9
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution:

> Only apply if you tooltip message is generic or equals, to each elements that take Selectize plugin in the View.

Use jQuery to set manually ToolTip options:

```
$(".selectize-control").tooltip({
    placement: "top", // position
    title: "Your Message"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created this code. I hope it helps you.

This is the way like I initialized my data to Selectize

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url : 'tableConfig',
    success : function(data) {
        $('#idTrans').each(function() {
            if (this.selectize) {
                let list = data.filter(x => x.codigo === "TRANS");
                for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
                    this.selectize.addOption({value:list[i].idConfiguracion, text: list[i].valor, title: list[i].descripcion});
                }
            }
        });
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        //alert("No se pudo realizar la operación por un error interno, contactese con el Administrador.");
    }
});
```

And then, I can customize the tooltip.

```
$('#idTrans').selectize({
    render: {
        option: function(data, escape) {
            let txtTitle = data.title;
            if(txtTitle === undefined || txtTitle === 'Ingrese Detalle:') txtTitle = '';

            return '<div class="option">' +
                '<div title="' + txtTitle + '">' + escape(data.text) + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
        },
        item: function(data, escape) {
            return '<div>'+ escape(data.text) + '</div>';
        }
    },
    onChange: function (value) {
        let tableConfig = $('#tableConfig').bootstrapTable('getData');
        let list = tableConfig.filter(x => x.idConfiguracion === parseInt(value));

        if (list.length > 0) {
            let idProTrans = list[0].nivel_padre;
            if (idProTrans !== null) {
                $("#idProceso_Trans").val(idProTrans);
            }
        }

    }
});
```

The property 'onChange'. Maybe, it isn't necessary for you and also you can delete that part.As you see, inside of render's property. I put 'title' for tooltip

Finally, looks like this.

[image]